# generate date range with calendar as input

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

is there a way to directly use

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
```

in order to subsequently generate a DatetimeIndex, which excludes holidays?

it does not seem like pd.bdate_range() can accept such an argument, but surely there must be some convenient way to accomplish this?

edit:

was able to create a frequency parameter with the CustomBusinessDay() class

```
USBDay = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
pd.bdate_range(start=start, end=end, freq=USBDay)
```

problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

solution:

was able to create a frequency parameter with the CustomBusinessDay() class

USBDay = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
pd.bdate_range(start=start, end=end, freq=USBDay)